# ¿como puedo limitar es uso de RAM arbitrariamente para un proceso en python? (un programa no compilado osea corriendo en el interprete)

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimización, data, ram

Estoy usando un chatbot pero ese chatbot carga su modelo en memoria RAM y pide mucha RAM
Note que los modelos que cargan info en memoria ram tardan mas en responder pero aun asi lo hacen pero mas lento, asumo que cargan y descargan la ram hasta encontrar la palabra que desean y el chatbot responde. Lo curioso es que en una PC de 4GB el chatbot pide todo lo que puede pedir osea 3,2GB de RAM pero en una PC de 8GB de RAM pide como maximo 5,1GB de RAM, y el bot necesita 6,3GB de RAM

Ahi noto como funciona lo que estaba pensando es hacer funcionar a ese programa de consola de python haciendole creer que de los 8GB tan solo hay 4 y que puede consumir has ahi nomas, incluso si pierde velocidad de respuesta(siento que es como si guardasen el texto en hojas ficticias en ram y que si no entran dividen su modelo entrenado en fragmentos de hojas tanto como puedan poner en RAM, y asi por medio de cargas y descargas de memoria llega a encontrar la respuesta deseada, por eso con algunas respuestas tardan mas que con otras, y en los casos en los que la ram es suficiente todas las respuestas se responden a la misma velocidad).
Hay algun modo de hacer que un programa reconozca que hay menos ram de lo que realmente hay limitandose a ese limite?

Encontre que era posible pero solo para linux, yo estaba buscando hacerlo en Windows 10

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41105733/limit-ram-usage-to-python-program

porque si haces esto no podras usar la libreria resources ya que aparentemente no existe en Windows, no se si alguno sabe si existe algun metodo desde el mismo windows, quizas algun programa de terceros descargado, o si tengo que ponerle algo a mi propio programa de python

Comment: Puede que te sirva esto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54949110/limit-python-script-ram-usage-in-windows

Comment: gracias lo estaré probando

Comment: El último párrafo hace que tu pregunta sea basada en opiniones,  estas pidiendo recomendaciones y eso no es buen visto. Creo que si lo borras y en su lugar pones una pregunta como *¿comobpuedo limitar la ram para un proceso en python?* quedaría mucho mejor y la pregunta seria muy interesante

Comment: Pase por lo mismo. Le puse 12 GB de RAM al PC y todo anduvo mucho mejor.

Comment: @Christian yo todavia no llegue a implementar ese code, pero lo de pedir recomendaciones es porque de momento no se si es posible, pero los modelos de generacion de texto se almacenan en grandes cantidades en RAM, yo probe con GPT 2 y con un algoritmo clasico personalizado hecho por mi y en ambos casos pasa lo mismo, que es una sobresaturacion de la RAM.
Claro con mas RAM quedaria solucionado, pero aun asi esa observacion de que "los modelos tienen a ocupar tanta RAM como sea posible" , me da la duda de la posibilidad de reducirles ese rango de RAM accesible a costa de velocidad de respuesta

Comment: es verdad, sin embargo no conozco alguna forma de limitar la RAM por lo que en este problema no puedo ayudar :(

Comment: Gracias igualmente, lo unico que me queda probar es lo que pasaron en el link de arriba pero parece algo complicado implementarlo, ya que con programas normales si se satura la ram da el tipico error. Pero con estos modelos de generacion de texto noto que es diferente es asunto, osea es como si cargara su modelo parcialmente y que con cargas y descargas de memoria llega a la respuesta deseada, con lo que puede que sea util limitar la RAM sin sufrir el error de falta de memoria

Comment: Creo que más te podría servir la [documentación](https://docs.python.org/3/library/resource.html#resource.RLIM_INFINITY) de un módulo

Comment: gracias lo estaré viendo haber si adapto mi modelo a eso.